# Recursive Uniform Distribution Expectation Question

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Suppose we draw some k ~ Unif(0, 1). Then, we will draw some $u_1$ ~ Unif(0, 1). If $u_1 < k,$ we stop. Else, we will draw $u_2$ ~ Unif(0, $u_1$). We will continue drawing until $u_n < k,$ where if we need to draw it, $u_n$ ~ Unif(0, $u_{n-1}$) What is the expected value for $n$? (i.e. how many draws until we get a value < k?)

I'm not sure how to calculate these like "infinite integrals"/infinite recursion, because we can see that like $p_1=k, p_2=(1-k)*\frac{k}{u_1}, p_3=(1-k)*\frac{u_1-k}{u_1}*\frac{k}{u_2},$ but I'm not sure how to think about the pattern/find a recursive pattern.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't super clear in the problem statement - the probability of drawing less than $k$ is constantly changing, because the distribution we pull from will change - I made an edit to the original question to make it clearer!

Comment: Ah. My apologies; the mistake was mine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_0=1$. First [note that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954557/ratio-distribution-of-max-and-min-for-uniform-random-variables):

$$k|k<u\sim\text{Unif}(0,u)$$

Therefore $k|k<u_i$ and $u_{i+1}$ are identically distributed and $P(k<u_{i+1}|k<u_i)=1/2$.

We conclude that $n$ follows a geometric distribution with parameter $p=1/2$.

This is easy to check with a quick simulation (in R):

```
m <- 1e7
k <- runif(m)
u <- runif(m)
p <- matrix(0L, 20, 2, 0, list(NULL, c("simulation", "dgeom")))

for (n in 1:20) {
  i <- which(u >= k)
  p[n, 1] <- length(k) - length(i)
  u <- runif(i, 0, u[i])
  k <- k[i]
}

p[,1] <- p[,1]/m
p[,2] <- dgeom(0:19, 0.5) # dgeom is 0-based
p
#>       simulation        dgeom
#>  [1,]  0.5003287 5.000000e-01
#>  [2,]  0.2499469 2.500000e-01
#>  [3,]  0.1247487 1.250000e-01
#>  [4,]  0.0624953 6.250000e-02
#>  [5,]  0.0312944 3.125000e-02
#>  [6,]  0.0155982 1.562500e-02
#>  [7,]  0.0077774 7.812500e-03
#>  [8,]  0.0038823 3.906250e-03
#>  [9,]  0.0019462 1.953125e-03
#> [10,]  0.0010004 9.765625e-04
#> [11,]  0.0004890 4.882812e-04
#> [12,]  0.0002456 2.441406e-04
#> [13,]  0.0001248 1.220703e-04
#> [14,]  0.0000615 6.103516e-05
#> [15,]  0.0000294 3.051758e-05
#> [16,]  0.0000164 1.525879e-05
#> [17,]  0.0000067 7.629395e-06
#> [18,]  0.0000042 3.814697e-06
#> [19,]  0.0000028 1.907349e-06
#> [20,]  0.0000006 9.536743e-07
```